# Docker Networking - nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have recently started migrating to Docker 1.9 and Docker-Compose 1.5's networking features to replace using links.

So far with links there were no problems with nginx connecting to my php5-fpm fastcgi server located in a different server in one group via docker-compose. Newly though when I run `docker-compose --x-networking up` my php-fpm, mongo and nginx containers boot up, however nginx quits straight away with `[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "waapi_php_1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:16`

However, if I run the docker-compose command again while the php and mongo containers are running (nginx exited), nginx starts and works fine from then on.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "42080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

php:
  build: config/docker/php
  ports:
    - "42022:22"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  env_file: config/docker/php/.env.development

mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "42017:27017"
  volumes:
    - /var/mongodata/wa-api:/data/db
  command: --smallfiles
```

This is my `default.conf` for nginx:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /var/www/test;

    error_log /dev/stdout debug;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        # Referencing the php service host (Docker)
        fastcgi_pass waapi_php_1:9000;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # We must reference the document_root of the external server ourselves here.
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/public$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

How can I get nginx to work with only a single docker-compose call?

Comment: I'm encountering this as well. I'm not sure if it's an error with the compose file, or a bug with docker networking itself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a possibility to use "volumes_from" as a workaround until depends_on feature (discussed below) is introduced. All you have to do is change your docker-compose file as below:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "42080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  volumes_from:
    - php

php:
  build: config/docker/php
  ports:
    - "42022:22"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  env_file: config/docker/php/.env.development

mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "42017:27017"
  volumes:
    - /var/mongodata/wa-api:/data/db
  command: --smallfiles
```

One big caveat in the above approach is that the volumes of php are exposed to nginx, which is not desired. But at the moment this is one docker specific workaround that could be used.

**depends_on feature**
This probably would be a futuristic answer. Because the functionality is not yet implemented in Docker (as of 1.9)

There is a proposal to introduce "depends_on" in the new networking feature introduced by Docker. But there is a long running debate about the same @ https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374 Hence, once it is implemented, the feature depends_on could be used to order the container start-up, but at the moment, you would have to resort to one of the following:

1. make nginx retry until the php server is up - I would prefer this one
2. use volums_from workaround as described above - I would avoid using this, because of the volume leakage into unnecessary containers.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @Gijs if you can post what your exact case is and what didn't work, someone could help on the forum.

Comment: volumes_from are deprecated

Comment: I ran into an issue in Azure App Service Docker Compose (preview) with this. Also had to make sure that any  `links:` I included in nginx used the same name as the service itself like `- my-service:my-service` or in this example `- mongo:mongo`.

Answer (score 64):

This can be solved with the mentioned `depends_on` directive since it's implemented now (2016):

```
version: '2'
  services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - "42080:80"
      volumes:
        - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      depends_on:
        - php

    php:
      build: config/docker/php
      ports:
        - "42022:22"
      volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
      env_file: config/docker/php/.env.development
      depends_on:
        - mongo

    mongo:
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - "42017:27017"
      volumes:
        - /var/mongodata/wa-api:/data/db
      command: --smallfiles
```

Successfully tested with:

```
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
```

Find more details in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends-on).

There is also a very interesting article dedicated to this topic: [Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: also check that the containers are correctly configured to be on the same network (source: kaos777s8 from [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/docker-nginx-emerg-host-not-found-in-upstream-web-3000))

Comment: This worked for me. In linux, I don't need "depends_on", but with them same git repository in WSL on windows 10, it was required, I don't know why.

Answer (score 27):

If you are so lost for read the last comment. I have reached another solution.

The main problem is the way that you named the services names.

In this case, if in your `docker-compose.yml`, the service for php are called "api" or something like that, you must ensure that in the file `nginx.conf` the line that begins with `fastcgi_pass` have the same name as the php service. i.e `fastcgi_pass api:9000;`

Lets say the php service name is `php_service` then the code will be:
In the file `docker-compose.yml`

```
php_service:
    build:
        dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
```

In the file `nginx.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php_service:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params; 
}
```

Comment: Never knew the name could be an issue. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 15):

You can set the max_fails and fail_timeout directives of nginx to indicate that the nginx should retry the x number of connection requests to the container before failing on the upstream server unavailability.

You can tune these two numbers as per your infrastructure and speed at which the whole setup is coming up. You can read more details about the health checks section of the below URL:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Following is the excerpt from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server
`max_fails=number`

> sets the number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the
>   server that should happen in the duration set by the fail_timeout
>   parameter to consider the server unavailable for a duration also set
>   by the fail_timeout parameter. By default, the number of unsuccessful
>   attempts is set to 1. The zero value disables the accounting of
>   attempts. What is considered an unsuccessful attempt is defined by the
>   proxy_next_upstream, fastcgi_next_upstream, uwsgi_next_upstream,
>   scgi_next_upstream, and memcached_next_upstream directives.

`fail_timeout=time`

> sets the time during which the specified number of unsuccessful
>   attempts to communicate with the server should happen to consider the
>   server unavailable; and the period of time the server will be
>   considered unavailable. By default, the parameter is set to 10
>   seconds.

To be precise your modified nginx config file should be as follows (this script is assuming that all the containers are up by 25 seconds at least, if not, please change the fail_timeout or max_fails in below upstream section):
Note: I didn't test the script myself, so you could give it a try!

```
upstream phpupstream {
   server waapi_php_1:9000 fail_timeout=5s max_fails=5;
}
server {
    listen  80;

    root /var/www/test;

    error_log /dev/stdout debug;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        # Referencing the php service host (Docker)
        fastcgi_pass phpupstream;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # We must reference the document_root of the external server ourselves here.
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/public$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Also, as per the following Note from docker (https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/networking.md#update-containers), it is evident that the retry logic for checking the health of the other containers is not docker's responsibility and rather the containers should do the health check themselves.

> **Updating containers**
>
> If you make a configuration change to a service and run docker-compose
>   up to update it, the old container will be removed and the new one
>   will join the network under a different IP address but the same name.
>   Running containers will be able to look up that name and connect to
>   the new address, but the old address will stop working.
>
> If any containers have connections open to the old container, they
>   will be closed. It is a container's responsibility to detect this
>   condition, look up the name again and reconnect.

Comment: This won't work.  read the caveat at the end of this section in the nginx docs:  "If there is only a single server in a group, max_fails, fail_timeout and slow_start parameters are ignored, and such a server will never be considered unavailable."

Comment: @Ferguzz that was a nice catch. As a workaround you can add two alias entries of the same container to make a group out of the same container.

Comment: As an alternate solution, I've provided in the same question use "volumes_from" to link the containers and make them wait until other containers are loaded. This is working for me.

Answer (score 11):

My problem was that I forgot to specify **network alias** in
docker-compose.yml in **php-fpm**

```
    networks:
      - u-online
```

It is works well!

```
version: "3"
services:

  php-fpm:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    container_name: php-fpm
    volumes:           
      - ./src:/var/www/basic/public_html
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    networks:
      - u-online
      
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:1.19.2
    container_name: nginx   
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm       
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/data/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./src:/var/www/basic/public_html
    networks:
      - u-online

#Docker Networks
networks:
  u-online:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: oh yes. I've passed through this so many times while trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

I believe Nginx dont take in account Docker resolver (127.0.0.11), so please, can you try adding:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11
```

in your nginx configuration file?

Comment: Add multiple resolvers like ``resolver 127.0.0.11 8.8.8.8;``

Comment: No as it will query in round robin as stated in the docs: Name servers are queried in a round-robin fashion.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem because there was two networks defined in my `docker-compose.yml`: one backend and one frontend.
When I changed that to run containers on the same default network everything started working fine.

Comment: This is far away from being an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found solution for services, that may be disabled for local development. Just use variables, that prevents emergency shutdown and works after service is available.

```
server {
    location ^~ /api/ {
        # other config entries omitted for breavity
    
        set $upstream http://api.awesome.com:9000;

        # nginx will now start if host is not reachable
        fastcgi_pass    $upstream; 
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
    }
}
```

source: https://sandro-keil.de/blog/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and solved it. Please add the following line to docker-compose.yml nginx section:

```
links:
  - php:waapi_php_1
```

Host in nginx config fastcgi_pass section should be linked inside docker-compose.yml nginx configuration.

Comment: Even though links is deprecated, this is the only thing that works for me. My problem was only happening when my containers was first spun up and could be fixed using docker-compose restart nginx. However adding the link was the only thing that worked for me to avoid the problem altogether. My code is at https://github.com/dcycle/starterkit-drupalsite/commit/04b2c47bacc6c61feced2ba08cd9e23011f9cacb

Answer (score 3):

At the first glance, I missed, that my "web" service didn't actually start, so that's why nginx couldn't find any host

```
web_1    | python3: can't open file '/var/www/app/app/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
web_1 exited with code 2
nginx_1  | [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "web:4044" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

Comment: hey i am having the same problem. My application is not running so i am getting the same error. i have put uwsgi-file as run.py in app.ini which should have run the app but its not happening

Answer (score 1):

Two things worth to mention:

- Using same network bridge
- Using `links` to add hosts resol

My example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tima@123
    network_mode: bridge
  ghost:
    image: ghost:2
    restart: always
    container_name: ghost
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      database__client: mysql
      database__connection__host: mysql
      database__connection__user: root
      database__connection__password: xxxxxxxxx
      database__connection__database: ghost
      url: https://www.itsfun.tk
    volumes:
      - ./ghost-data:/var/lib/ghost/content
    network_mode: bridge
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - ghost
    links:
      - ghost
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
       - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
       - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
       - ./nginx/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    network_mode: bridge
```

If you don't specify a special network bridge, all of them will use the same default one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) section to your nginx container configuration.

You have to make visible the `php` container to the `nginx` container.

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "42080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  links:
    - php:waapi_php_1
```

Comment: I know about links, however Docker marked them deprecated in version 1.9 that came out a week ago in favor of using Docker's networking. I would like a solution that uses that, partly because links have an issue with circular linking that networking shouldn't have.

Comment: In [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) I don't see `link` being deprecated. Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't see that in there either; however when I run `docker-compose --x-networking up` with links defined in my `docker-compose.yml`, I get this clear warning: `WARNING: 
"nginx" defines links, which are not compatible with Docker networking and will be ignored.
Future versions of Docker will not support links - you should remove them for forwards-compatibility.`

Comment: Ok i [found](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/networking.md) where the deprecation is. The only idea I have is: is you `docker-compose.yml` file in a folder named `waapi` ?

Comment: Yes, it is in a folder named `waapi`

Comment: Hm.. who knows if the order matter. Try to put the php block before the nginx block in `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 0):

With links there is an order of container startup being enforced. Without links the containers can start in any order (or really all at once).

I think the old setup could have hit the same issue, if the `waapi_php_1` container was slow to startup.

I think to get it working, you could create an nginx entrypoint script that polls and waits for the php container to be started and ready.

I'm not sure if nginx has any way to retry the connection to the upstream automatically, but if it does, that would be a better option.

Comment: And how do I do polling?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like docker-gen to dynamically update nginx configuration when your backend is up.

See:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/docker-gen/
- https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

I believe Nginx+ (premium version) contains a resolve parameter too (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best choice to avoid linking containers issues are the *docker networking* features

But to make this work, docker creates entries in the */etc/hosts* for each container from assigned names to each container.

> with docker-compose --x-networking -up is something like
>   [docker_compose_folder]-[service]-[incremental_number]

To not depend on unexpected changes in these names you should use the parameter

> container_name

in your docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
php:
      container_name: waapi_php_1
      build: config/docker/php
      ports:
        - "42022:22"
      volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
      env_file: config/docker/php/.env.development
```

Making sure that it is the same name assigned in your configuration file for this service. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this, but it is a good approach to start.

Answer (score 0):

My Workaround (after much trial and error):

- In order to get around this issue, I had to get the **full name** of the 'upstream' Docker container, found by running `docker network inspect my-special-docker-network` and getting the full `name` property of the upstream container as such:

  ```
  "Containers": {
       "39ad8199184f34585b556d7480dd47de965bc7b38ac03fc0746992f39afac338": {
            "Name": "my_upstream_container_name_1_2478f2b3aca0",
  ```
- Then used this in the NGINX `my-network.local.conf` file in the `location` block of the `proxy_pass` property: (Note the addition of the GUID to the container name):

  ```
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://my_upsteam_container_name_1_2478f2b3aca0:3000;
  ```

As opposed to the previously working, but now broken:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream_container_name_1:3000
```

Most likely cause is a recent change to Docker Compose, in their default naming scheme for containers, as listed [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6316).

This seems to be happening for me and my team at work, with latest versions of the Docker `nginx` image:

- I've opened issues with them on the docker/compose GitHub [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6370)

Answer (score 0):

this error appeared to me because my `php-fpm` image enabled `cron`, and I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

in your docker-compose.yml file change your Nginx service follow:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "42080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

When using NGINX as a reverse proxy, one way to get this bug consistently under `docker compose` is to have a names mismatch between the **upstream app service name** - key entered in the `docker-compose.yml` for the (upstream) app (e.g. `jenkins:` rather than `jenkins2:` below) and the **`server` name** entered in the `ssl.conf` file in the `upstream` section of this config file, e.g. thus:

- *conf.d/ssl.conf:*

```
upstream jenkins_upstream {
    server jenkins2:54182; # as intended
}

# [..]
```

vs.

- *docker-compose.yml:*

```
services:

  jenkins: # INCORRECT! WILL RAISE ERROR AS BELOW
  # jenkins2: # this would be correct given `ssl.conf` above

    image: 'mirekphd/jenkins-jdk17-on-ubuntu2204:latest'
    container_name: jenkins_jenkins
    # [..]
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:54182:54182'
    # [..]
   
  nginx:
    image: 'bitnami/nginx:latest'
    container_name: jenkins_nginx
    # [..]
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8444:8444"
    # [..]
```

...will result in this error message after Jenkins and NGINX are started with `docker compose`:

```
nginx 09:50:13.86 INFO  ==> ** Starting NGINX **
2023/09/05 09:50:13 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "jenkins2:54182" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:4
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "jenkins2:54182" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app and nginx should have the same networks in order to communicate the one with each other.

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "42080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./config/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  networks:
    - myappnet
    - nginxnet

php:
  build: config/docker/php
  ports:
    - "42022:22"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  env_file: config/docker/php/.env.development
  networks:
    - myappnet
    - nginxnet


networks:
    - myappnet:
    - nginxnet:
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream` as well, so I managed to solve it, by adding `depends_on` directive to nginx service in `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score -3):

(new to nginx)
In my case it was wrong folder name

For config

```
upstream serv {
    server ex2_app_1:3000;
}
```

make sure the app folder is in ex2 folder:

ex2/app/...