# nginx opensource in kubernetes not reaching services

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I have a [nginx open source](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/nginx/#installing-the-chart) pod (not ingress controller) in a namespace  and i have configured the `upstream` in it with 2 services already there like below

```
## @param serverBlock Custom server block to be added to NGINX configuration
## PHP-FPM example server block:
serverBlock: |-
  upstream samplecluster {


  server acj-prip:9111;
  server acj-scpp:9111;
  resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

  }
  server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;  
  server_name _;


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://samplecluster/;
  }

  }
```

For some reason nginx is not reaching this, these services are reachable from other pods though, getting the error as below

```
host not found in upstream "acj-prip:9111" in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/server-block.conf:6
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "acj-prip:9111" in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/server-block.conf:6
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Are *acj-prip* and *acj-scpp* in the same namespace of nginx? If yes, you must use full DNS name to resolve these; for example *acj-prip.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local*.

Comment: They are in same namespace , same error, even after adding fulldns name

Comment: Try removing `acj-prip:9111` config and let the nginx pod starts. Then go to the pod and try `curl acj-prip:9111` or `wget -qO- acj-prip:9111` or `ping acj-prip`. Does the service resolve? Do you get any response?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720618/docker-nginx-stopped-emerg-11-host-not-found-in-upstream

Comment: @Andromeda it seems to be a debian image with no tools

Comment: Refer to this [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639138/docker-networking-nginx-emerg-host-not-found-in-upstream). Let me know if it helps